# Javascript function for iteration and HTML implementation

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am making a online computer store and I am trying to make a login jsp for admin and other users.
The thing I want to do but don't know how, because I am not so good with JavaScript is to go through my ArrayList of users and if the user has an attribute `isLoggedIn == true`, to display this chunk of code

```
<a class="whiteOff" href="AdminLogin?logoff">Izloguj se (<%=k.getIme() %>)</a>
<a class="hide" href="register.jsp">Registracija</a>
<a class="hide" href="adminLogin.jsp">Logovanje za administratore</a>
<a class="hide" href="userLogin.jsp">Logovanje za korisnike</a><br/>
```

and if that is not true to display this

```
<a class="hide" href="AdminLogin?logoff">Izloguj se (<%=k.getIme() %>)</a>
<a class="white" href="register.jsp">Registracija</a>
<a class="white" href="adminLogin.jsp">Logovanje za administratore</a>
<a class="white" href="userLogin.jsp">Logovanje za korisnike</a><br/>
```

I have done this in jsp like so

```
<%for(Korisnik k : Baza.getUser()){%>
                <% if(k.loggedIn){%>
                    <a class="whiteOff" href="AdminLogin?logoff">Izloguj se (<%=k.getIme() %>)</a>
                    <a class="hide" href="register.jsp">Registracija</a>
                    <a class="hide" href="adminLogin.jsp">Logovanje za administratore</a>
                    <a class="hide" href="userLogin.jsp">Logovanje za korisnike</a><br/>
                <% } else{%>
                    <a class="hide" href="AdminLogin?logoff">Izloguj se (<%=k.getIme() %>)</a>
                    <a class="white" href="register.jsp">Registracija</a>
                    <a class="white" href="adminLogin.jsp">Logovanje za administratore</a>
                    <a class="white" href="userLogin.jsp">Logovanje za korisnike</a><br/>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
```

but the problem there is when I register new users I have double links,3 users triple and so on. When I log into a user I set his loggedIn attribute to true, now when the loggon attribute is true I would like to display those code at the top, but not in double triple and so on, you get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your iteration or HTML code, it is a design problem. When a user requests your page, the JSP will render links for *all* users that are in the `Baza.getUser()` collection.

Instead what you want is to identify which user you are going to serve the page to, and to only render the HTML for that user. You need to keep track somewhere in your server-side-logic of what user is requesting a page. Once you have that you can do something like

```
<% if (Baza.getCurrentUser().loggedIn) { %>
    <a class="whiteOff" href="AdminLogin?logoff">Izloguj se (<%=k.getIme() %>)</a>
    <a class="hide" href="register.jsp">Registracija</a>
    <a class="hide" href="adminLogin.jsp">Logovanje za administratore</a>
    <a class="hide" href="userLogin.jsp">Logovanje za korisnike</a><br/>
<% } else{%>
    <a class="hide" href="AdminLogin?logoff">Izloguj se (<%=k.getIme() %>)</a>
    <a class="white" href="register.jsp">Registracija</a>
    <a class="white" href="adminLogin.jsp">Logovanje za administratore</a>
    <a class="white" href="userLogin.jsp">Logovanje za korisnike</a><br/>
<% } %>
```